# How to monkey-patch a single line of code in a third-party Python module?

Tags: python, module, monkeypatching

Below is an excerpt of some code from a third-party Python module that I'm using in a large project.

```py
class LockedStream(object):
    file = None
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file

    def write(self, x):
        with input_lock:
            self.file.write(x)

    def flush(self):
        return getattr(self.file, 'flush', lambda: None)()

original_stdout, original_stderr = sys.stdout, sys.stderr
sys.stdout, sys.stderr = map(LockedStream, (sys.stdout, sys.stderr)) # <- PROBLEM LINE
```

The line highlighted causes another module to crash because the change it makes is incompatible with what the other module is expecting. Removing this line would solve the problem immediately, but future updates to the module would reverse the change, on top of it being a hacky solution. Were this line inside of a function/class, I could monkey-patch the function/class, but as it is it's unclear to me what the best practice for getting rid of this line is. Possible approaches to fix this issue, none of which seem ideal, are listed below:

1. Remove this line by directly modifying the third-party module.
2. Monkey patch the LockedStream class in such a way that it doesn't break the other module or this one.
3. Change the order of imports so the module that would be broken gets loaded before this troublesome change happens.

I'm currently using approach 3, but this hardly seems like an elegant solution. Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated. Thanks for your help.